# Resources for hierarchical modelling in R

Tags: r, references, multilevel-analysis

Just chasing a text/resource for learning hierarchical modelling in (and) R. I have extensive experience using Matlab and Stata but very limited R experience.

Any recommendations? Happy to purchase material if necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want a practical guide to fitting mixed models / multilevel models, then the link provided by Mark White is a very good one:

https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer

However, if you seek to understand the theory, then I would highly recommend looking at mixed models - of which multilevel models can be thought of as a sub-type, then I would suggest the following:

Demidenko, E. (2013). Mixed models: theory and applications with R. John Wiley & Sons.

Bates, D. M. (2010). [lme4: Mixed-effects modeling with R.](http://webcom.upmf-grenoble.fr/LIP/Perso/DMuller/M2R/R_et_Mixed/documents/Bates-book.pdf)

Bates, D., Mächler, M., Bolker, B., & Walker, S. (2014). [Fitting linear mixed-effects models using lme4. arXiv preprint arXiv:1406.5823.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.5823)

The latter two are both available for free on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is: https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer. He shows both commonly-used packages, and he includes the equations alongside the code—so you can easily reference back to books from there.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these:

GLMM FAQ Ben Bolker and others: https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html

nlme package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/nlme.pdf, which allows non- linear mixed models and correlations structures

glmmTMB: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/glmmTMB.pdf

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I built R a package recently on Bayesian network modeling.

In the [package description page](https://chenhaotian.github.io/Bayesian-Bricks/#table-of-contents) you'll find varies examples of **hierarchical models**, their CPDs, graphical models structures, learning/inference algorithms and the corresponding **R code**.

Comment: could you give the name of the package in case your link dies in the future? Thanks!

Comment: the name is `bbricks`, you can install it by `install.packages("bbricks")`

Answer (score 1):

I find this resource very helpful, it also contains methods for cross-sectional nested data:

https://methodenlehre.github.io/intro-to-rstats/hierarchical-linear-models.html