# Confusion about replication in ANOVA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, repeated-measures

**Set Up**

It's about finding out which formulation (concentration in percentage) and soaking time of formulation yields to a better measured outcome.

In the table below, **Minutes** represent soaking time while the *Percentage* columns represent the different formulations and its elements being the measured outcome. Then lastly *Trials* represent the repetition of the experiment. Is this *trial* synonymous to *Replication*?

| Trials | Minutes | 100% | 75% | 50% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 18.28 | 94.58 | 52.1 |
| 1 | 15 | 13.32 | 70.69 | 67.2 |
| 1 | 30 | 11.03 | 115.66 | 38.95 |
| 2 | 5 | 13.97 | 47.25 | 113.52 |
| 2 | 15 | 22.73 | 76.68 | 89.88 |
| 2 | 30 | 8.15 | 27.45 | 56.76 |
| 3 | 5 | 12.13 | 72.41 | 86 |
| 3 | 15 | 16.55 | 91.91 | 84.51 |
| 3 | 30 | 16.25 | 61.78 | 69.99 |

What I am curious about is the practice of others when dealing with the Trials. They just get the mean for all the trials resulting to the table below and then proceed to doing ANOVA with it.

| MINUTES | 100% | 75% | 50% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 14.79333333 | 71.41333333 | 83.87333333 |
| 15 | 17.53333333 | 79.76 | 80.53 |
| 30 | 11.81 | 68.29666667 | 55.23333333 |

**The Question:**

Is this how ANOVA is done in Experimental Designs?  I just feel like the Trials are meant to be preserved throughout the analysis and not summarised into a single quantity.

**Edit**

Each trial is a repetition of the entire experiment. The formulations and soaking time are tested again but on a different but identical batch

Comment: For clarification, does "trial 1" mean that a single sample of formulation was tested three times, at 5/15/30 minutes, so that table actually contains three samples, each tested three times? In that case, a repeated measures ANOVA would be appropriate. Or are these really nine different samples? In that case, one could treat them as independent. In any case, it makes little sense to average first, then run ANOVA, that discards information, though from what I have seen, that seems to be quite a common approach in biological sciences.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Why RM-ANOVA and not a MLM?   Also, I've never worked with biologists, but ... that sounds like a really bad practice!  (I work with social scientists and they also do cockamamie things).

Comment: @PeterFlom: repeated measures because I learned my stats long ago, and from psychology literature... I was about to ask you for literature on MLM or GEE, but will first search through CV. Biologists: as I said, I have only very little visibility here, but what I have seen does not make me happy from a statistical point of view. This kind of "averaging-before-analyzing", even smaller sample sizes and even more degrees of freedom than in other disciplines, rampant use of dynamite plots for just five data points, etc.

Comment: @PeterFlom: looking at [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/388011/1352), is MLM simply mixed effects modeling? If so, that is what I was thinking of, and I should have been more precise in that repeated measures is a special case of that. If not, any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Yes, I think those are the same. The terminology around these models is really confusing! What I mean is a model like $Y = X\beta + Z\gamma + \epsilon$

Comment: @PeterFlom: thanks, that clears matters up (for me, at least; I hope OP is not overly confused). For the record, I absolutely agree with your answer, and have upvoted.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Indeed. I heard this practice in chemistry and biology department and the way they phrased it sounded like something "obvious"  but the loss of information just keeps me scratching my head

Answer (score 2):

"Replication", at least in my experience, usually means something else. It means repeating the whole experiment or study. (However, use of terms varies by field, so maybe "replicate" is right in your field.)

If I understand what you did, then you set things to soak in some liquid at different concentrations, and then measured something else at 5. 15, and 30 minutes.

If that is correct, then yes, you should account for that. There are several methods. The oldest is repeated measures ANOVA, but this makes some assumptions that are unrealistic (mostly sphericity) and many researchers nowadays prefer either a multilevel model or  generalized estimating equations (GEE).

Both of these have extensive literatures and have been discussed here many times.

Comment: Yes. Your analogy is correct., sir. I have thought of Repeated Measures ANOVA but I am not sure which variable to set as the unique ID or how should one generate according to this set up.

Comment: Your ID can be anything..  From the table you provide, "trials" would be the ID. But, again, I'd not do RM-ANOVA.

Comment: Ah arbitrary ID I suppose. I'll look into GEE as suggested. I just want to wrap my head around how Trials are handled in the analysis.